# Can same linked list function that adds to end of the list be used to add to many diffrent linked lists?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

This is my linked list function that adds the new node to the end of the list.

```
void addNodeAtTail( struct Student *student, struct Courses *newNode )
  {
      newNode->next = NULL;           // sucessor of newNode is NULL, because newNode becomes tail of list
      if ( student->list == NULL )
          student->list = newNode;    // if list is empty, newNode will be head of list
  else
  {
      struct Courses *temp = student->list;
      while( temp->next != NULL ) // search last element in list
          temp = temp->next;
      temp->next = newNode;       // successor of last node is newNode
  }
  }
```

Can this same function be used for adding a node to a diffrent linked list that I may have? Or do I have to create another function because we are dealing with another struct?

Answer (score 0):

If the object you are trying to add is not `struct Courses *newNode` then you will not be able to add it with this function. If you need a generic linked list you will need to mess around with passing `void *` which is lots of fun. Here is a reasonable tutorial for this:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no, because your are explicitely dealing with instances of `struct Courses`.
If you want a generic list, use a cons-cell:

```
struct list { 
   struct list* next;
   void* data;
}
```

Also, lists in C can be embedded in other structs. See for example [this explanation](https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) on how lists are used in the Linux kernel. Here is a snippet taken from the article:

```
struct my_cool_list{
    struct list_head list; /* kernel's list structure */
    int my_cool_data;
    void* my_cool_void;
};
```